# Relation between prime numbers and the exponential of powers of two

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing, contest-math

This question is from my math olympiad textbook. The exercise says that :

I want to prove :

> If $x^y +1 $ with integer $x>1$ is prime , then $x$ must be even and $y$ must be a power of two ($1$ is also possible).

I thought that if $x^y +1 $ is prime ,then it must be odd number ,so $x^y$ is even and $x$ is even. However , i could not manage to show that $y=2^m$.

Can you help me to show it ?

Comment: The community appreciates your efforts to provide context and format in mathjax as a beginner!

Comment: For a help, see also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3809033/verify-my-proof-that-for-any-n1-if-nn1-is-prime-then-n-22k-for-so?noredirect=1).

Comment: If $y$ has an odd prime factor , say $p$ , then $x^{y/p}+1$ is a nontrivial factor of $x^y+1$

Comment: If $x=6$ and $y=1$, then $x^y + 1 = 7$ .. so .. I miss something, no ?

Comment: @MrSmithGoesToWashington You are right that $y=1$ is also possible.

Comment: If $y>1$ is a power of $2$ , such a number is also called Generalized Fermat number.

Comment: @GeoffreyTrang $7$ is no Fermat prime. The next possible prime of this form is $F_{33}=2^{2^{33}}+1$

Comment: For the same reason that primes that are $1$ more than powers of $2$ with positive exponents must be Fermat primes (of which only $3, 5, 17, 257,$ and $65537$ are known).

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I accidentally included the non-Fermat prime $7$ in the list. It has been fixed now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Proof by contrapositive: Let the factorisation of $y$ be $y=2^M \cdot s$, where $s$ is an odd number, $s>1$ and $M\geq 0$, $M$ is an integer. Then, $$x^y+1=\bigg(x^{(2^M)}\bigg)^s+1$$$$=(x^{(2^M)}+1)\left(\bigg(x^{(2^M)}\bigg)^{s-1}-\bigg(x^{(2^M)}\bigg) ^{s-2}+…+1\right)$$ which is a product of two factors each greater than $1$. Hence it is composite.

Thus for the desired expression to be prime, $y$ must be of the form $2^m$ for some $m$.

Comment: So you assume that y is even .. ?

Comment: No I don’t. M could be 0 as well. I will add that bit. If M=0, then the expression is divisible by x+1.